# Есть пример кода, но я не понимаю как он работает

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i,m_len,fl_k(-1),fl_n(-1),ns,ks,red(0);
char s[30]={'\0'};
printf("Vvedite radock: ");
gets(s);
for(i=(strlen(s)+1);i>=0;i--)
      s[i+1]=s[i];
      s[0]=' ';
      m_len=strlen(s);
for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {
     if(s[i]==' '&&s[i+1]!=' '&&fl_n==-1&&fl_k==-1)
     { ns=i+1;
       fl_n=1;
     }
if(s[i]!=' '&&(s[i+1]==' '||s[i+1]=='\0')&&fl_n==1&&fl_k==-1)
       { ks=i;
         fl_k=1;
       }
if(fl_k==1&&fl_n==1)
       { if((ks-ns+1)<m_len)
         m_len=(ks-ns+1);
         fl_k=-1;
         fl_n=-1;
       }
    }
if(m_len==strlen(s))
printf("V radcky nema sliv\n");
else
   {
for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {
if(strchr(s,' ')&&s[i+1]!=' '&&fl_n==-1&&fl_k==-1)
      { ns=i+1;
        fl_n=1;
      }
if(s[i]!=' '&&(s[i+1]==' '||s[i+1]=='\0')&&fl_n==1&&fl_k==-1)
       { ks=i;
         fl_k=1;
       }
if(fl_k==1&&fl_n==1)
       { if((ks-ns+1)==m_len&&m_len!=1&&red==0)
      {
    if(m_len%2==0)
        { ns+=m_len/2;
    for(i=(strlen(s)+1);i>=ns;i--)
           s[i+1]=s[i];
           s[ns]=' ';
           red=1;
        }
    else
       { for(i=ks;i<=(strlen(s)+1);i++)
          s[i]=s[i+1];
    ns+=(m_len-1)/2;
    for(i=(strlen(s)+1);i>=ns;i--)
          s[i+1]=s[i];
          s[ns]=' ';
          red=1;
       }
      }
      fl_n=-1;
      fl_k=-1;
       }
    }
for(i=0;i<=(strlen(s)+1);i++)
    s[i]=s[i+1];
printf("Obrobleniy radock:\n");
puts(s);
 }
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Мне нужно переделать этот чтобы он выполнил условие.
Примечание. Предложением будем считать последовательность слов, разделенных символом (символами) пробела, которая заканчивается символом «.», Но не более 30-ти символов.
Словом будем считать последовательность любых символов кроме пробелов.
При разработке алгоритма решения задачи, учесть возможность следующих вариантов:
а) предложение может быть пустым;
б) предложение может быть длиной больше 30-ти символов, тогда обрабатывать только первых 30-ти символов.
в) слова могут разделяться не одним, а большим количеством символов пробела;
г) предложение может состоять только из одного слова;
д) предложение может состоять только из символов пробела.
Самое длинное слово (первое из самых длинных, если их несколько) разбить на два слова пополам. Если в этом слове нечетное количество символов, то первый символ слова удалить.

Код что я скинул выполняет условие:
В введенном предложении короткое слово (первое из самых коротких, если их несколько) разбить на два слова пополам. Если в этом слове нечетное количество символов, то последний символ слова удалить.

Comment: Ну возьмите gdb и пройдитесь по нему ... и да , метка С++ а в коде С...

Comment: @Beeen007: Зачем вы поменяли метку? Этот код написан на С++, а не на С (см. `fl_k(-1)`). Хотя функции `gets` уже давно нет ни там, ни там.

Comment: Явно `c++`, только вот я не понимаю, зачем такие ужасы =))))

Comment: Ужасы тут, конечно, зашкаливают...

Comment: Начиная с того, что если я правильно понял, признаком отсутствия слов являтся число повторяющихся пробелов равным длине строки... код написан *почетным индусом*. Ограничение длины и наличие точки не рассматривается, мы можем выйти за границу массива..